# NameError: name 'UTC' is not defined

Tags: python, datetime

The output of `datetime.datetime.now()` outputs in my native timezone of UTC-8. I'd like to convert that to an appropriate timestamp with a tzinfo of UTC.

```
from datetime import datetime, tzinfo
x = datetime.now()
x = x.replace(tzinfo=UTC)
```

^ outputs NameError: name 'UTC' is not defined

`x.replace(tzinfo=<UTC>)` outputs SyntaxError: invalid syntax

`x.replace(tzinfo='UTC')` outputs TypeError: tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'str'

What is the correct syntax to use to accomplish my example?

Comment: Python's standard libraries don't include any tzinfo classes, including UTC. The documentation does include instructions for creating one though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to use an additional library such as `pytz`. Python's `datetime` module doesn't include any `tzinfo` classes, including UTC, and certainly not your local timezone.

Edit: as of [Python 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3.2/whatsnew/3.2.html#datetime-and-time) the `datetime` module includes a `timezone` object with a `utc` member. The canonical way of getting the current UTC time is now:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
x = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```

You'll still need another library such as `pytz` for other timezones.  Edit: [Python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/release/3.9.0/whatsnew/3.9.html#zoneinfo) now includes the [`zoneinfo` module](https://docs.python.org/release/3.9.0/library/zoneinfo.html#module-zoneinfo) so there's no need to install additional packages.

Comment: Thanks! For those curious, ended up using `x.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc) + timedelta(hours=8)`

Answer (score 4):

If all you're looking for is the time now in UTC, datetime has a builtin for that:

```
x = datetime.utcnow()
```

Unfortunately it doesn't include any tzinfo, but it does give you the UTC time.

Alternatively if you do need the tzinfo you can do this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
x = datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('UTC'))
```

You may also be interested in a list of the timezones: [Python - Pytz - List of Timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866926/python-pytz-list-of-timezones)