# Is there a list of Pytz Timezones?

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone, pytz

I would like to know what are all the possible values for the timezone argument in the Python library pytz. How to do it?

Comment: Note: time zone handling is part of the standard library [since Python 3.9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64861179/10197418). Use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html). pytz is [deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/).

Comment: Specifically there is [`zoneinfo.available_timezones()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html#zoneinfo.available_timezones)

Answer (score 600, accepted):

You can list all the available timezones with `pytz.all_timezones`:

```
In [40]: import pytz
In [41]: pytz.all_timezones
Out[42]: 
['Africa/Abidjan',
 'Africa/Accra',
 'Africa/Addis_Ababa',
 ...]
```

There is also `pytz.common_timezones`:

```
In [45]: len(pytz.common_timezones)
Out[45]: 403

In [46]: len(pytz.all_timezones)
Out[46]: 563
```

Comment: In addition to `all_timezones`, [pytz also provides](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#helpers) `common_timezones`.

Comment: why is China missing?

Comment: China uses a [single timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_China#IANA_time_zone_database), whose timezone name is `'Asia/Shanghai'`.

Comment: This expression shows the terrible result pytz can give: `(datetime(2017,2,13,14,29,29, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai')) - datetime(2017,2,13,14,29,29, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('UTC'))).total_seconds()` (the result is *not* -28800). I will avoid pytz—dateutil.tz provides similar functionalities but uses the OS timezone database and has no such problems.

Comment: @YongweiWu it is a wrong API usage. You shouldn't pass a pytz timezone with a non-fixed utc offset as a tzinfo argument directly. Use .localize() method as the pytz docs suggest.

Comment: @jfs I know now. See my answer below and the discussions there.

Comment: For a complete list of timezones for a particular country, use `pytz.country_timezones`. 
Example: `pytz.country_timezones['us']`
It uses ISO 3166 country code for a lookup. It returns a list: `['America/New_York', 'America/Detroit', ...]`

Comment: Additionally, for a subset of `pytz.all_timezones` you can use a list comprehension:  
`[x for x in pytz.all_timezones if "australia" in x.lower()]`  or filter: 
`list(filter(lambda x: "australia" in x.lower(), pytz.all_timezones))`

Comment: It's weird to include Asia/Shanghai, Asia/Chongqing, etc. but miss Asia/Beijing. This is the only timezone we used in China.

Answer (score 90):

**Don't create your own list** - `pytz` has a built-in set:

```
import pytz
set(pytz.all_timezones_set)  
>>> {'Europe/Vienna', 'America/New_York', 'America/Argentina/Salta',..}
```

You can then **apply a timezone**:

```
import datetime
tz = pytz.timezone('Pacific/Johnston')
ct = datetime.datetime.now(tz=tz)
>>> ct.isoformat()
2017-01-13T11:29:22.601991-05:00
```

Or **if you already have a `datetime` object** that is **TZ aware** (not naive):

```
# This timestamp is in UTC
my_ct = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.UTC)

# Now convert it to another timezone
new_ct = my_ct.astimezone(tz)
>>> new_ct.isoformat()
2017-01-13T11:29:22.601991-05:00
```

Answer (score 47):

The timezone name is the only reliable way to specify the timezone.

You can find a list of timezone names here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
Note that this list contains a lot of alias names, such as US/Eastern for the timezone that is properly called America/New_York.

If you programatically want to create this list from the zoneinfo database you can compile it from the zone.tab file in the zoneinfo database. I don't think pytz has an API to get them, and I also don't think it would be very useful.

Comment: Letting people choose their timezone from a list is quite useful. Plenty of websites and Linux installers do that already.

Answer (score 33):

Here is a Python list of country codes, names, continents, capitals, and pytz timezones:

```
countries = [
  {'timezones': ['Europe/Paris'], 'code': 'FR', 'continent': 'Europe', 'name': 'France', 'capital': 'Paris'}
  {'timezones': ['Africa/Kampala'], 'code': 'UG', 'continent': 'Africa', 'name': 'Uganda', 'capital': 'Kampala'},
  {'timezones': ['Asia/Colombo'], 'code': 'LK', 'continent': 'Asia', 'name': 'Sri Lanka', 'capital': 'Sri Jayewardenepura Kotte'},
  {'timezones': ['Asia/Riyadh'], 'code': 'SA', 'continent': 'Asia', 'name': 'Saudi Arabia', 'capital': 'Riyadh'},
  {'timezones': ['Africa/Luanda'], 'code': 'AO', 'continent': 'Africa', 'name': 'Angola', 'capital': 'Luanda'},    
  {'timezones': ['Europe/Vienna'], 'code': 'AT', 'continent': 'Europe', 'name': 'Austria', 'capital': 'Vienna'},
  {'timezones': ['Asia/Calcutta'], 'code': 'IN', 'continent': 'Asia', 'name': 'India', 'capital': 'New Delhi'},
  {'timezones': ['Asia/Dubai'], 'code': 'AE', 'continent': 'Asia', 'name': 'United Arab Emirates', 'capital': 'Abu Dhabi'},
  {'timezones': ['Europe/London'], 'code': 'GB', 'continent': 'Europe', 'name': 'United Kingdom', 'capital': 'London'},
]
```

For the full list, see this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/mjrulesamrat/0c1f7de951d3c508fb3a20b4b0b33a98).

Answer (score 18):

**Available from Python 3.9:**

`zoneinfo`, new module in Python 3.9 which works with the database of IANA.

In order to grab all the available timezones, first:

```py
pip install tzdata
```

And then:

```py
import zoneinfo

print(zoneinfo.available_timezones())
```

Comment: This is also noted on the `pytz` homepage: "Projects using Python 3.9 or later should be using the support now included as part of the standard library, and third party packages work with it such as tzdata. pytz offers no advantages beyond backwards compatibility with code written for earlier versions of Python."

Answer (score 17):

**EDIT: I would appreciate it if you do not downvote this answer further.** This answer is *wrong*, but I would rather retain it as a historical note. While it is arguable whether the pytz interface is error-prone, it can do things that dateutil.tz cannot do, especially regarding daylight-saving in the past or in the future. I have honestly recorded my experience in an article ["Time zones in Python"](https://yongweiwu.wordpress.com/2019/09/01/time-zones-in-python/).

---

If you are on a Unix-like platform, I would suggest you avoid pytz and look just at /usr/share/zoneinfo. dateutil.tz can utilize the information there.

The following piece of code shows the problem pytz can give. I was shocked when I first found it out. (Interestingly enough, the pytz installed by yum on CentOS 7 does not exhibit this problem.)

```
import pytz
import dateutil.tz
from datetime import datetime
print((datetime(2017,2,13,14,29,29, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai'))
     - datetime(2017,2,13,14,29,29, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('UTC')))
     .total_seconds())
print((datetime(2017,2,13,14,29,29, tzinfo=dateutil.tz.gettz('Asia/Shanghai'))
     - datetime(2017,2,13,14,29,29, tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzutc()))
     .total_seconds())

-29160.0
-28800.0
```

I.e. the timezone created by pytz is for the true local time, instead of the standard local time people observe. Shanghai conforms to +0800, not +0806 as suggested by pytz:

```
pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai')
<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Shanghai' LMT+8:06:00 STD>
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to Mark Ransom's comment and downvote, now I know I am using pytz the wrong way. In summary, you are not supposed to pass the result of `pytz.timezone(…)` to `datetime`, but should pass the `datetime` to its `localize` method.

Despite his argument (and my bad for not reading the pytz documentation more carefully), I am going to keep this answer. I was answering the question in one way (how to enumerate the supported timezones, though not with pytz), because I believed pytz did not provide a correct solution. Though my belief was wrong, this answer is still providing some information, IMHO, which is potentially useful to people interested in this question. Pytz's *correct* way of doing things is counter-intuitive. Heck, if the *tzinfo* created by pytz should not be directly used by `datetime`, it should be a different type. The pytz interface is simply badly designed. **The link provided by Mark shows that many people, not just me, have been misled by the pytz interface.**

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473721/weird-timezone-issue-with-pytz/11474330 for a fix. There's nothing wrong with `pytz`, you're just using it wrong. P.S. This is not an answer to the question *at all*.

Comment: @MarkRansom Good info, and it is nice to know. However, I do not buy your argument. The interface is designed wrong, period. It is very much counterintuitive.

Comment: Yes, the interface is designed wrong. But it's the `datetime` interface that's wrong, not `pytz`. `datetime` did not anticipate *intelligent* timezone objects, so its interface does not initialize them properly.

Comment: With respect, I disagree. `datetime` is part of the standard Python library, and it is pytz that should follow the `datetime` interface, not vice versa. If anybody could implement some interface in the way they think better without consensus, there would be no robust software.

Comment: As I said, `pytz` can't follow the `datetime` interface because the `datetime` interface is deficient. The authors of that interface did not anticipate the problems of a timezone whose parameters change over the years. Just because it's part of the standard Python distribution does not mean it's perfect.

Comment: If the standard interface is deficient, live with it. Do not break it. If pytz really needs to do something special, make the result of `pytz.timezone` incompatible with the `tzinfo` parameter of `datetime`. It is better to make the program stop than generate incorrect results.

Comment: I had a chance to revisit this answer while looking for something else completely different.  As noted on another answer, the documentation for `pytz` recommends using the built-in support (`zoneinfo` module) instead in Python 3.9 or later.  I believe the `datetime` interface was enhanced so that `ZoneInfo` could operate without the problems `pytz` had.  It looks at this time like the `pytz` author has no interest in updating the package to use the new capabilities.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks for the info: it is really good to know. Finally, we need neither `localize` nor `normalize`.

Answer (score 11):

For pytz , could use below in for loop.

```
for tz in pytz.all_timezones:
    print(tz)
```

So output will be in line by line.

```
Africa/Douala
Africa/El_Aaiun
Africa/Freetown
Africa/Gaborone
Africa/Harare
```

As mentioned in eary answers, below is also works.

```
print(pytz.all_timezones)
```

It prints everything in an array,

```
['Africa/Abidjan', 'Africa/Accra', 'Africa/Addis_Ababa', 'Africa/Algiers', 'Africa/Asmara', 'Africa/Asmera', 'Africa/Bamako', 'Africa/Bangui', 'Africa/Banjul', 'Africa/Bissau', 'Africa/Blantyre', 'Africa/Brazzaville', 'Africa/Bujumbura', 'Africa/Cairo', 'Africa/Casablanca', 'Africa/Ceuta', 'Africa/Conakry', 'Africa/Dakar', 'Africa/Dar_es_Salaam', 'Africa/Djibouti', 'Africa/Douala', 'Africa/El_Aaiun', 'Africa/Freetown', 'Africa/Gaborone', 'Africa/Harare', 'Africa/Johannesburg', 'Africa/Juba', 'Africa/Kampala', 'Africa/Khartoum', 'Africa/Kigali', 'Africa/Kinshasa', 'Africa/Lagos', 'Africa/Libreville', 'Africa/Lome', 'Africa/Luanda', 'Africa/Lubumbashi', 'Africa/Lusaka', 'Africa/Malabo', 'Africa/Maputo', 'Africa/Maseru', 'Africa/Mbabane', 'Africa/Mogadishu', 'Africa/Monrovia', 'Africa/Nairobi', 'Africa/Ndjamena', 'Africa/Niamey', 'Africa/Nouakchott', 'Africa/Ouagadougou', 'Africa/Porto-Novo', 'Africa/Sao_Tome', 'Africa/Timbuktu', 'Africa/Tripoli', 'Africa/Tunis', 'Africa/Windhoek', 'America/Adak', 'America/Anchorage', 'America/Anguilla', 'America/Antigua', 'America/Araguaina', 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires', 'America/Argentina/Catamarca', 'America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia', 'America/Argentina/Cordoba', 'America/Argentina/Jujuy', 'America/Argentina/La_Rioja', 'America/Argentina/Mendoza', 'America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos', 'America/Argentina/Salta', 'America/Argentina/San_Juan', 'America/Argentina/San_Luis', 'America/Argentina/Tucuman', 'America/Argentina/Ushuaia', 'America/Aruba', 'America/Asuncion', 'America/Atikokan', 'America/Atka', 'America/Bahia', 'America/Bahia_Banderas', 'America/Barbados', 'America/Belem', 'America/Belize', 'America/Blanc-Sablon', 'America/Boa_Vista', 'America/Bogota', 'America/Boise', 'America/Buenos_Aires', 'America/Cambridge_Bay', 'America/Campo_Grande', 'America/Cancun', 'America/Caracas', 'America/Catamarca', 'America/Cayenne', 'America/Cayman', 'America/Chicago', 'America/Chihuahua', 'America/Coral_Harbour', 'America/Cordoba', 'America/Costa_Rica', 'America/Creston', 'America/Cuiaba', 'America/Curacao', 'America/Danmarkshavn', 'America/Dawson', 'America/Dawson_Creek', 'America/Denver', 'America/Detroit', 'America/Dominica', 'America/Edmonton', 'America/Eirunepe', 'America/El_Salvador', 'America/Ensenada', 'America/Fort_Nelson', 'America/Fort_Wayne', 'America/Fortaleza', 'America/Glace_Bay', 'America/Godthab', 'America/Goose_Bay', 'America/Grand_Turk', 'America/Grenada', 'America/Guadeloupe', 'America/Guatemala', 'America/Guayaquil', 'America/Guyana', 'America/Halifax', 'America/Havana', 'America/Hermosillo', 'America/Indiana/Indianapolis', 'America/Indiana/Knox', 'America/Indiana/Marengo', 'America/Indiana/Petersburg', 'America/Indiana/Tell_City', 'America/Indiana/Vevay', 'America/Indiana/Vincennes', 'America/Indiana/Winamac', 'America/Indianapolis', 'America/Inuvik', 'America/Iqaluit', 'America/Jamaica', 'America/Jujuy', 'America/Juneau', 'America/Kentucky/Louisville', 'America/Kentucky/Monticello', 'America/Knox_IN', 'America/Kralendijk', 'America/La_Paz', 'America/Lima', 'America/Los_Angeles', 'America/Louisville', 'America/Lower_Princes', 'America/Maceio', 'America/Managua', 'America/Manaus', 'America/Marigot', 'America/Martinique', 'America/Matamoros', 'America/Mazatlan', 'America/Mendoza', 'America/Menominee', 'America/Merida', 'America/Metlakatla', 'America/Mexico_City', 'America/Miquelon', 'America/Moncton', 'America/Monterrey', 'America/Montevideo', 'America/Montreal', 'America/Montserrat', 'America/Nassau', 'America/New_York', 'America/Nipigon', 'America/Nome', 'America/Noronha', 'America/North_Dakota/Beulah', 'America/North_Dakota/Center', 'America/North_Dakota/New_Salem', 'America/Nuuk', 'America/Ojinaga', 'America/Panama', 'America/Pangnirtung', 'America/Paramaribo', 'America/Phoenix', 'America/Port-au-Prince', 'America/Port_of_Spain', 'America/Porto_Acre', 'America/Porto_Velho', 'America/Puerto_Rico', 'America/Punta_Arenas', 'America/Rainy_River', 'America/Rankin_Inlet', 'America/Recife', 'America/Regina', 'America/Resolute', 'America/Rio_Branco', 'America/Rosario', 'America/Santa_Isabel', 'America/Santarem', 'America/Santiago', 'America/Santo_Domingo', 'America/Sao_Paulo', 'America/Scoresbysund', 'America/Shiprock', 'America/Sitka', 'America/St_Barthelemy', 'America/St_Johns', 'America/St_Kitts', 'America/St_Lucia', 'America/St_Thomas', 'America/St_Vincent', 'America/Swift_Current', 'America/Tegucigalpa', 'America/Thule', 'America/Thunder_Bay', 'America/Tijuana', 'America/Toronto', 'America/Tortola', 'America/Vancouver', 'America/Virgin', 'America/Whitehorse', 'America/Winnipeg', 'America/Yakutat', 'America/Yellowknife', 'Antarctica/Casey', 'Antarctica/Davis', 'Antarctica/DumontDUrville', 'Antarctica/Macquarie', 'Antarctica/Mawson', 'Antarctica/McMurdo', 'Antarctica/Palmer', 'Antarctica/Rothera', 'Antarctica/South_Pole', 'Antarctica/Syowa', 'Antarctica/Troll', 'Antarctica/Vostok', 'Arctic/Longyearbyen', 'Asia/Aden', 'Asia/Almaty', 'Asia/Amman', 'Asia/Anadyr', 'Asia/Aqtau', 'Asia/Aqtobe', 'Asia/Ashgabat', 'Asia/Ashkhabad', 'Asia/Atyrau', 'Asia/Baghdad', 'Asia/Bahrain', 'Asia/Baku', 'Asia/Bangkok', 'Asia/Barnaul', 'Asia/Beirut', 'Asia/Bishkek', 'Asia/Brunei', 'Asia/Calcutta', 'Asia/Chita', 'Asia/Choibalsan', 'Asia/Chongqing', 'Asia/Chungking', 'Asia/Colombo', 'Asia/Dacca', 'Asia/Damascus', 'Asia/Dhaka', 'Asia/Dili', 'Asia/Dubai', 'Asia/Dushanbe', 'Asia/Famagusta', 'Asia/Gaza', 'Asia/Harbin', 'Asia/Hebron', 'Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh', 'Asia/Hong_Kong', 'Asia/Hovd', 'Asia/Irkutsk', 'Asia/Istanbul', 'Asia/Jakarta', 'Asia/Jayapura', 'Asia/Jerusalem', 'Asia/Kabul', 'Asia/Kamchatka', 'Asia/Karachi', 'Asia/Kashgar', 'Asia/Kathmandu', 'Asia/Katmandu', 'Asia/Khandyga', 'Asia/Kolkata', 'Asia/Krasnoyarsk', 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur', 'Asia/Kuching', 'Asia/Kuwait', 'Asia/Macao', 'Asia/Macau', 'Asia/Magadan', 'Asia/Makassar', 'Asia/Manila', 'Asia/Muscat', 'Asia/Nicosia', 'Asia/Novokuznetsk', 'Asia/Novosibirsk', 'Asia/Omsk', 'Asia/Oral', 'Asia/Phnom_Penh', 'Asia/Pontianak', 'Asia/Pyongyang', 'Asia/Qatar', 'Asia/Qostanay', 'Asia/Qyzylorda', 'Asia/Rangoon', 'Asia/Riyadh', 'Asia/Saigon', 'Asia/Sakhalin', 'Asia/Samarkand', 'Asia/Seoul', 'Asia/Shanghai', 'Asia/Singapore', 'Asia/Srednekolymsk', 'Asia/Taipei', 'Asia/Tashkent', 'Asia/Tbilisi', 'Asia/Tehran', 'Asia/Tel_Aviv', 'Asia/Thimbu', 'Asia/Thimphu', 'Asia/Tokyo', 'Asia/Tomsk', 'Asia/Ujung_Pandang', 'Asia/Ulaanbaatar', 'Asia/Ulan_Bator', 'Asia/Urumqi', 'Asia/Ust-Nera', 'Asia/Vientiane', 'Asia/Vladivostok', 'Asia/Yakutsk', 'Asia/Yangon', 'Asia/Yekaterinburg', 'Asia/Yerevan', 'Atlantic/Azores', 'Atlantic/Bermuda', 'Atlantic/Canary', 'Atlantic/Cape_Verde', 'Atlantic/Faeroe', 'Atlantic/Faroe', 'Atlantic/Jan_Mayen', 'Atlantic/Madeira', 'Atlantic/Reykjavik', 'Atlantic/South_Georgia', 'Atlantic/St_Helena', 'Atlantic/Stanley', 'Australia/ACT', 'Australia/Adelaide', 'Australia/Brisbane', 'Australia/Broken_Hill', 'Australia/Canberra', 'Australia/Currie', 'Australia/Darwin', 'Australia/Eucla', 'Australia/Hobart', 'Australia/LHI', 'Australia/Lindeman', 'Australia/Lord_Howe', 'Australia/Melbourne', 'Australia/NSW', 'Australia/North', 'Australia/Perth', 'Australia/Queensland', 'Australia/South', 'Australia/Sydney', 'Australia/Tasmania', 'Australia/Victoria', 'Australia/West', 'Australia/Yancowinna', 'Brazil/Acre', 'Brazil/DeNoronha', 'Brazil/East', 'Brazil/West', 'CET', 'CST6CDT', 'Canada/Atlantic', 'Canada/Central', 'Canada/Eastern', 'Canada/Mountain', 'Canada/Newfoundland', 'Canada/Pacific', 'Canada/Saskatchewan', 'Canada/Yukon', 'Chile/Continental', 'Chile/EasterIsland', 'Cuba', 'EET', 'EST', 'EST5EDT', 'Egypt', 'Eire', 'Etc/GMT', 'Etc/GMT+0', 'Etc/GMT+1', 'Etc/GMT+10', 'Etc/GMT+11', 'Etc/GMT+12', 'Etc/GMT+2', 'Etc/GMT+3', 'Etc/GMT+4', 'Etc/GMT+5', 'Etc/GMT+6', 'Etc/GMT+7', 'Etc/GMT+8', 'Etc/GMT+9', 'Etc/GMT-0', 'Etc/GMT-1', 'Etc/GMT-10', 'Etc/GMT-11', 'Etc/GMT-12', 'Etc/GMT-13', 'Etc/GMT-14', 'Etc/GMT-2', 'Etc/GMT-3', 'Etc/GMT-4', 'Etc/GMT-5', 'Etc/GMT-6', 'Etc/GMT-7', 'Etc/GMT-8', 'Etc/GMT-9', 'Etc/GMT0', 'Etc/Greenwich', 'Etc/UCT', 'Etc/UTC', 'Etc/Universal', 'Etc/Zulu', 'Europe/Amsterdam', 'Europe/Andorra', 'Europe/Astrakhan', 'Europe/Athens', 'Europe/Belfast', 'Europe/Belgrade', 'Europe/Berlin', 'Europe/Bratislava', 'Europe/Brussels', 'Europe/Bucharest', 'Europe/Budapest', 'Europe/Busingen', 'Europe/Chisinau', 'Europe/Copenhagen', 'Europe/Dublin', 'Europe/Gibraltar', 'Europe/Guernsey', 'Europe/Helsinki', 'Europe/Isle_of_Man', 'Europe/Istanbul', 'Europe/Jersey', 'Europe/Kaliningrad', 'Europe/Kiev', 'Europe/Kirov', 'Europe/Lisbon', 'Europe/Ljubljana', 'Europe/London', 'Europe/Luxembourg', 'Europe/Madrid', 'Europe/Malta', 'Europe/Mariehamn', 'Europe/Minsk', 'Europe/Monaco', 'Europe/Moscow', 'Europe/Nicosia', 'Europe/Oslo', 'Europe/Paris', 'Europe/Podgorica', 'Europe/Prague', 'Europe/Riga', 'Europe/Rome', 'Europe/Samara', 'Europe/San_Marino', 'Europe/Sarajevo', 'Europe/Saratov', 'Europe/Simferopol', 'Europe/Skopje', 'Europe/Sofia', 'Europe/Stockholm', 'Europe/Tallinn', 'Europe/Tirane', 'Europe/Tiraspol', 'Europe/Ulyanovsk', 'Europe/Uzhgorod', 'Europe/Vaduz', 'Europe/Vatican', 'Europe/Vienna', 'Europe/Vilnius', 'Europe/Volgograd', 'Europe/Warsaw', 'Europe/Zagreb', 'Europe/Zaporozhye', 'Europe/Zurich', 'GB', 'GB-Eire', 'GMT', 'GMT+0', 'GMT-0', 'GMT0', 'Greenwich', 'HST', 'Hongkong', 'Iceland', 'Indian/Antananarivo', 'Indian/Chagos', 'Indian/Christmas', 'Indian/Cocos', 'Indian/Comoro', 'Indian/Kerguelen', 'Indian/Mahe', 'Indian/Maldives', 'Indian/Mauritius', 'Indian/Mayotte', 'Indian/Reunion', 'Iran', 'Israel', 'Jamaica', 'Japan', 'Kwajalein', 'Libya', 'MET', 'MST', 'MST7MDT', 'Mexico/BajaNorte', 'Mexico/BajaSur', 'Mexico/General', 'NZ', 'NZ-CHAT', 'Navajo', 'PRC', 'PST8PDT', 'Pacific/Apia', 'Pacific/Auckland', 'Pacific/Bougainville', 'Pacific/Chatham', 'Pacific/Chuuk', 'Pacific/Easter', 'Pacific/Efate', 'Pacific/Enderbury', 'Pacific/Fakaofo', 'Pacific/Fiji', 'Pacific/Funafuti', 'Pacific/Galapagos', 'Pacific/Gambier', 'Pacific/Guadalcanal', 'Pacific/Guam', 'Pacific/Honolulu', 'Pacific/Johnston', 'Pacific/Kanton', 'Pacific/Kiritimati', 'Pacific/Kosrae', 'Pacific/Kwajalein', 'Pacific/Majuro', 'Pacific/Marquesas', 'Pacific/Midway', 'Pacific/Nauru', 'Pacific/Niue', 'Pacific/Norfolk', 'Pacific/Noumea', 'Pacific/Pago_Pago', 'Pacific/Palau', 'Pacific/Pitcairn', 'Pacific/Pohnpei', 'Pacific/Ponape', 'Pacific/Port_Moresby', 'Pacific/Rarotonga', 'Pacific/Saipan', 'Pacific/Samoa', 'Pacific/Tahiti', 'Pacific/Tarawa', 'Pacific/Tongatapu', 'Pacific/Truk', 'Pacific/Wake', 'Pacific/Wallis', 'Pacific/Yap', 'Poland', 'Portugal', 'ROC', 'ROK', 'Singapore', 'Turkey', 'UCT', 'US/Alaska', 'US/Aleutian', 'US/Arizona', 'US/Central', 'US/East-Indiana', 'US/Eastern', 'US/Hawaii', 'US/Indiana-Starke', 'US/Michigan', 'US/Mountain', 'US/Pacific', 'US/Samoa', 'UTC', 'Universal', 'W-SU', 'WET', 'Zulu']
```

Answer (score 10):

They appear to be populated by the *tz database time zones* found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

[image]

Comment: `pytz` provides access to [the tz database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tz-link.html) (it is the source for the wikipedia data).

Comment: specified in [PEP 615](https://peps.python.org/pep-0615/)

Answer (score 4):

you will find all the `pytz` supported timezones here:

https://gist.github.com/heyalexej/8bf688fd67d7199be4a1682b3eec7568

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30085479)

Comment: you are right. you can call me Lazy @Rainald62

Answer (score 2):

Also, I understood that we can provide a comprehensive list for all `pytz` timezones with the help of `country_timezones` and `country_names` from this library:

```py
In [1]: from pytz import country_names, country_timezones

In [2]: all_timezones = [country_timezones.get(country) for country in country_names]

In [3]: all_timezones
Out[3]:
[['Europe/Andorra'],
 ['Asia/Dubai'],
 ['Asia/Kabul'],
 ['America/Antigua'],
 ['America/Anguilla'],
 ['Europe/Tirane'],
 ['Asia/Yerevan'],
 ['Africa/Luanda'],
 ['Antarctica/McMurdo',
  'Antarctica/Casey',
  'Antarctica/Davis',
  'Antarctica/DumontDUrville',
  'Antarctica/Mawson',
  'Antarctica/Palmer
  ...
```

In addition, there is another way to get a common list of timezones names, which will be provided by `common_timezones_set`:

```py
In [1]: from pytz import common_timezones_set

In [2]: list(common_timezones_set)
Out[2]:
['Pacific/Palau',
 'Africa/Algiers',
 'Pacific/Pohnpei',
 'Africa/Brazzaville',
 'America/Goose_Bay',
 'America/North_Dakota/Beulah',
 'Africa/Kinshasa',
 'America/Whitehorse',
 'America/Sao_Paulo',
 'Asia/Jerusalem',
 'Canada/Atlantic',
 'America/Santiago',
 'America/Adak',
 'Pacific/Efate',
 ...
```

References:

- [**`Country Information`** <sup>[pytz-docs]</sup>](https://pytz.sourceforge.net/index.html?highlight=country_names#country-information)
- [**`Helpers`** <sup>[pytz-docs]</sup>](https://pytz.sourceforge.net/index.html?highlight=common_timezones_set)