# What's the error in the MySQL statement?

Tags: python, mysql

i use the python shell and execute an 'insert' sql, it appears "SyntaxError: invalid syntax", anyone could tell me what's the error in my MySQL statement? thanks

```
cursor.execute("insert into monitor_task (job_id, task_id, host, port, active, last_attempt_time, last_status last_message, last_success_time, last_metrics, last_metrics_raw) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", [1L, 0, 'hh-hadoop-srv-ct01.bj', 11101, True, datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 2, '', datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), '', ''])
  File "<console>", line 1
    cursor.execute("insert into monitor_task (job_id, task_id, host, port, active, last_attempt_time, last_status last_message, last_success_time, last_metrics, last_metrics_raw) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", [1L, 0, 'hh-hadoop-srv-ct01.bj', 11101, True, datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 2, '', datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), '', ''])
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and desc the table monitor_task:

```
mysql> desc monitor_task;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| job_id            | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| task_id           | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| host              | varchar(128) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| port              | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| active            | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_attempt_time | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_status       | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_message      | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_success_time | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_metrics      | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_metrics_raw  | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The arrow is pointing to where you're going wrong. You can't say `tzinfo=<UTC>`, you need an actual tzinfo object.

Comment: `last_status last_message` syntax is wrong. there must be a comma. ie `last_status,last_message`

Comment: @suhail yes, i have fix it for the syntax error. thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

`SyntaxError` is a Python error. The syntax error is in the `datetime` object creation:

```
datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

`tzinfo=<UTC>` is a Python syntax error:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[You can find here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692906/python-datetime-tzinfo-time-zone-names-documentation) how to provide a valid `tzinfo` argument.