# How can I convey text descriptions of location time zones to UTC based in Python?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, timezone

I need to be able to convert a time zone stored as a string that is region based either to a UTC time zone or a common time zone across locations. For example, “Canada/Vancouver” and “Americas/Los_Angeles” should both resolve to “US/Pacific”. This solution should also work for other time zones like “Canada/Toronto” and “AmericA/New_York” to “US/Eastern”, also extending to time zones for other locations like Mexico, etc.

I have no idea how to do this or even think about this. I could convert it to a UTC-7 but that doesn’t handle PST vs PDT shifts.

Can someone help?

Edit: after reading the comments and answer I realized that my question wasn’t clear enough.
I have a set of phone numbers, and I use the “phonenumbers” package to get the time zone out in the newer format for each number, but I want to count the number of unique phone numbers by the old region time zone naming convention. Hence I want to convert to newer “Continent/City” time zones to “Country/Region” time zones.  . The UTC was just me trying to think of a way to convert the region/city formats into a common name.

Comment: The package `pytz` can be of help. Do you have an example timestamp?

Comment: I don’t want to do this with timestamp, I want to convert to newer “Continent/City” time zones to “Country/Region” time zones. 

I have a set of phone numbers, and I use the phone numbers package to get the time zone out in the newer format, but I want to count the number of unique phone numbers by the old region time zone naming convention. The UTC was just me trying to think of a way to convert the region/city formats into a common name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) as from the [IANA database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) refer to regions in a geographical sense. UTC on the other hand is not a time zone, it is *universal* (not specific to a region).

- For a time zone, you can have an offset from UTC (like `UTC-8` for 8 hours behind UTC).
- A certain date/time in a given time zone has a specific UTC offset, as derived from the rules for that time zone (when to apply DST etc.).
- The other way around, a certain UTC offset can apply in *multiple* time zones at given date/time, so mapping back needs a definition, otherwise it's ambiguous.

Regarding the naming of time zones, "Continent/City"-style time zone names are preferred. Old names like "US/Pacific" (as from before 1993) are kept in the database for backwards-compatibility - see also [eggert-tz/backward](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/main/backward).

Python >= 3.9 supports IANA time zones with the standard library via the [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) module. Using that, you can create aware datetime objects easily and get their UTC offset, e.g. like

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

tznames = ["America/Vancouver", "America/Los_Angeles",
           "America/Toronto", "America/New_York", "Europe/Berlin"]

def timedelta_to_str(td):
    hours, seconds = divmod(td.total_seconds(), 3600)
    return f"{int(hours):+}:{int(seconds/60):02d}"

now = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)

for z in tznames:
    local_now = now.astimezone(ZoneInfo(z))
    print(f"now in zone {z}:\n\t{local_now.isoformat(' ', timespec='seconds')}, "
          f"UTC offset: {timedelta_to_str(local_now.utcoffset())} hours\n")
    # or also e.g. print(f"local time {z}:\n\t{local_now}, UTC offset: {local_now.strftime('%z')}\n")

# now in zone America/Vancouver:
#   2022-01-12 06:30:08-08:00, UTC offset: -08:00 hours

# now in zone America/Los_Angeles:
#   2022-01-12 06:30:08-08:00, UTC offset: -08:00 hours

# now in zone America/Toronto:
#   2022-01-12 09:30:08-05:00, UTC offset: -05:00 hours

# now in zone America/New_York:
#   2022-01-12 09:30:08-05:00, UTC offset: -05:00 hours

# now in zone Europe/Berlin:
#   2022-01-12 15:30:08+01:00, UTC offset: +01:00 hours
```

see also on SO:

- [Python: datetime tzinfo time zone names documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15692906/10197418)
- [Display the time in a different time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1398674/10197418)
- [Format timedelta to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/format-timedelta-to-string)

Comment: I don’t want to do this with timestamp, I want to convert to newer “Continent/City” time zones to “Country/Region” time zones. I have a set of phone numbers, and I use the”phonenumbers” package to get the time zone out in the newer format, but I want to count the number of unique phone numbers by the old region time zone naming convention. The UTC was just me trying to think of a way to convert the region/city formats into a common name. But I think I can do that with the eggertz-to/backward package. Thanks!

Comment: @BradDavis then what about defining a time zone to region mapping? Or just use the UTC offset as "region"? If you have a date, I don't see a problem with this

Comment: Yup, you are 100% correct. You helped me better understand the problem, thank you!