# List of all timezones listed in pytz.all_timezones

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I've been searching around for the contents of pytz.all_timezones, but have found nothing. Just people saying "Use pytz.all_timezones" but that would mean I'd have to copy every single timezone from the output. I need a LIST of all timezones in pytz.all_timezones, not just a message telling me to use it.

Comment: what specifically is your question? btw. `pytz` is deprecated, try to avoid using it. Instead, use zoneinfo; see [here for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64861179/10197418) how to obtain available tz names.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer mentioned, `pytz.all_timezones` is already a list of strings. In your code, you could access this list and extract the values you need from it: there is probably no need to create a different list for that.

You could save the content of the timezones list to a text file like this:

```
# open file in write mode
with open(r'pytz_all_timezones.txt', 'w') as fp:
    for item in pytz.all_timezones:
        # write each item on a new line
        fp.write(f"{item}\n")
```

Comment: I can't copy the output though

Comment: Where do you want to copy the output? And for what purpose?

Comment: I needed a list of timezones for my Discord bot to give to people (it'd clog things up if it were sent in messages)

Comment: Just give them this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones