# Python in time or Datetime, List all time zones available

Tags: python, datetime, time, timezone

Is the a way to list All timezones for Time and Datetime library in Python

so it can be used as options to get time in respective timezone

like in the example

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone    

south_africa = timezone('Africa/Johannesburg')
sa_time = datetime.now(south_africa)
print sa_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
```

Comment: Note: time zone handling is part of the standard library [since Python 3.9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64861179/10197418). Use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html). pytz is [deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/).

Answer (score 0):

```
In [4]: len(pytz.all_timezones)
Out[4]: 583

In [5]: pytz.all_timezones[::20]
Out[5]: 
['Africa/Abidjan',
 'Africa/Douala',
 'Africa/Mbabane',
 'America/Argentina/Catamarca',
 'America/Belize',
 'America/Curacao',
 'America/Guatemala',
 'America/Kentucky/Louisville',
 'America/Mexico_City',
 'America/Port-au-Prince',
 'America/St_Barthelemy',
 'Antarctica/Davis',
 'Asia/Baghdad',
 'Asia/Harbin',
 'Asia/Kuching',
 'Asia/Saigon',
 'Asia/Vientiane',
 'Australia/Broken_Hill',
 'Brazil/Acre',
 'EST5EDT',
 'Etc/GMT-11',
 'Europe/Athens',
 'Europe/Lisbon',
 'Europe/Simferopol',
 'GMT+0',
 'Jamaica',
 'Pacific/Easter',
 'Pacific/Norfolk',
 'ROC',
 'W-SU']
```