# python - explanation on different timezone string format for the same

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

Why `datetime.datetime` created with `zoneinfo.ZoneInfo` timezone gives different timezone string with its `tzinfo` attribute?

[Using ZoneInfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html#using-zoneinfo) document says:

> ZoneInfo is a concrete implementation of the datetime.tzinfo abstract base class, and is intended to be attached to tzinfo, either via the constructor, the datetime.replace method or datetime.astimezone:

If `ZoneInfo` is attached to `tzinfo` of the datetime instance that has been created with it, then why  creating with **Australia/Melbourne** gives different name **AEDT**?

```
datetime.datetime.now(tz=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo("Australia/Melbourne")).astimezone().tzinfo
---
datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=39600), 'AEDT')
```

And **AEDT** is not recognized by `ZoneInfo`.

```
datetime.datetime.now(tz=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo("AEDT")).astimezone().tzinfo
---
ZoneInfoNotFoundError: 'No time zone found with key AEDT'
```

Please help understand what the different here and how to inter-operate among different timezone string e.g. **AEDT** and **Australia/Melbourne**.

Comment: Melbourne switches between AEST and AEDT depending on the time of year. This is why you don't typically instantiate times using either of those timezones, since they might not even exist (trying to create a time in summer with the winter timezone doesn't make much sense). So you're supposed to use the location name line `Australia/Melbourne`, which then lets Python decide whether AEDT or AEST are appropriate. Apparently ZoneInfo doesn't even support instantiating AEDT directly, but I'm not sure of the details there.

Comment: Do `'AEST'` or `'AET'` work?  And what does `datetime.datetime.now(tz=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo("AEDT")).astimezone().tzinfo.zone` return?

Answer (score 1):

Note that you're dealing with two different situations here. ***#1*** you set a `zoneinfo.ZoneInfo` timezone. ***#2*** you set a `timedelta`-derived timezone. To clarify:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

#1
now_tz = datetime.now(ZoneInfo("Europe/Berlin"))
print(now_tz.tzinfo)
print(repr(now_tz.tzinfo))
# Europe/Berlin
# zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Berlin')

#2
now_local = datetime.now().astimezone()
print(now_local.tzinfo)
print(repr(now_local.tzinfo))
# CET
# datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600), 'CET')
```

While zoneinfo gives you a proper [IANA db](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) tz name (not the potentially ambiguous abbreviation), the timedelta-tz only has the abbreviation. `astimezone(None)` calls into [_local_timezone](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4a929d432b48775096d40f5c72bcd9be052b0a2d/Lib/_pydatetime.py#L1988), which calls your platform's [`mktime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/mktime) implementation. If that just gives you the abbreviation, then the abbreviation is all that Python can show you.

Side note: to get all the available time zones, use `zoneinfo.available_timezones()`. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15692906/10197418).