# Django - ValueError: Invalid timezone: u'Asia/Seoul ROK'

Tags: django, timezone

I had a problem with template tag "timezone" for a while.

```
## template
{% load tz %}
{% timezone 'Asia/Seoul ROK' %}
    {{ reservation.datetime|date:"G:i A e" }}
{% endtimezone %}
```

I already write USE_TZ = True / TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Seoul ROK'
And I also installed pytz module and move the module on to 
my project (I am developing django on eclipse pydev.)

And whenever I run the project i face the error below.

```
Invalid timezone: u'Asia/Seoul ROK'
```

How could I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Asia/Seoul` maybe?

There is no such timezone as `Asia/Seoul ROK` in `pytz.all_timezones`.

**Edit**: So `Asia/Seoul` gives you the same error.

Maybe pytz isn't getting imported.

This is where the error comes from in `django/utils/timezone.py`:

```
try:
    import pytz
except ImportError:
    pytz = None
...
...
if isinstance(timezone, tzinfo):
    _active.value = timezone
elif isinstance(timezone, six.string_types) and pytz is not None:
    _active.value = pytz.timezone(timezone)
else:
    raise ValueError("Invalid timezone: %r" % timezone)
```

This most probably means pytz is None after all and you get the error.

Does any other timezone work? If not, then pytz import must be the problem.

Comment: I finally resolve this prob by moving pytz folder. The reason was exactly what u wrote. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not much familiar with pytz. But i think you should look at this

[Python - Pytz - List of Timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866926/python-pytz-list-of-timezones)

Try Asia/Seoul

I tried it in python shell and got same error

```
>>> a = pytz.timezone("Asia/Seoul ROK")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytz-2014.7-py2.7.egg/pytz/__init__.py", line 180, in timezone

pytz.exceptions.UnknownTimeZoneError: 'Asia/Seoul ROK'
```

Comment: Change the settings TIME ZONE also.  Seehttps://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/timezones/