# How to convert c# timezone id to python acceptable id?

Tags: c#, python, timezone

Is there any timezone mapping method from c# to python?

for example, from [c# timezone id](http://www.xiirus.net/articles/article-_net-convert-datetime-from-one-timezone-to-another-7e44y.aspx) to [python timezone list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866926/python-pytz-list-of-timezones)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to translate between Windows and IANA time zones?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348807/how-to-translate-between-windows-and-iana-time-zones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert MS Windows timezone names ("c# timezone") to tzdata/Olsen timezone names (pytz "python timezone list") you could use http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml
 file e.g., to autogenerate the mapping, you could use [`get_windows_info.py` Python 3 script](https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal/blob/master/get_windows_info.py).

Comment: thx, I found similar answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348807/how-to-translate-between-windows-and-iana-time-zones but python script +1

Comment: This answer seems to be obsolete - the links are not working anymore

Comment: windowsZones.xml is now located here: https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/main/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml