# TIME_ZONE entry

Tags: python, django

I'm going through the django tutorial, when they ask me to enter the TIME_ZONE I don't know how to do it right. I have entered

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'
```

What is the correct terminology for the timezone?

Answer (score 3):

When timezone aware, django uses [`pytz`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/) to validate the timezone.

This means every entry in [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866926/python-pytz-list-of-timezones) can be used. `America/New_York` is in that list, so it should be valid to use.