# Django settings TIME_ZONE syntax

Tags: django, django-settings

I have spent several hours searching and have been unable to determine what the TIME_ZONE syntax should be. I am currently in Mexico.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Pytz - List of Timezones?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866926/python-pytz-list-of-timezones)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify Mexican time zone as `TIME_ZONE = 'America/Mexico_City'`.
Please refer this [link](https://gist.github.com/pamelafox/986163) for more information on pytz timezones.