# In Pandas, what is the best way to use tz_localize for a time series which ignores DST?

Tags: python, pandas, localization, dst

I have a time series which was measured by a sensor with clock that doesn't adjust according to DST rules. Therefore, the datetime data is independent of DST. What is the best way to localize this data in Pandas?

Answer (score 3):

You can localize to a non-changing time zone first, for example EST, then use `tz_convert()` to change it to a time zone region which automatically detects daylight savings, for example US/Eastern.

```
In [16]: a=pd.DataFrame(dict(t=(pd.Timestamp('01/01/2017'), pd.Timestamp('07/01/2017'))))

In [17]: a
Out[17]:
           t
0 2017-01-01
1 2017-07-01

In [18]: a.t=a.t.dt.tz_localize('EST')

In [19]: a
Out[19]:
                          t
0 2017-01-01 00:00:00-05:00
1 2017-07-01 00:00:00-05:00

In [20]: a.t=a.t.dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')

In [21]: a
Out[21]:
                          t
0 2017-01-01 00:00:00-05:00
1 2017-07-01 01:00:00-04:00
```

By default pandas uses pytz for time zones; you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866926/python-pytz-list-of-timezones) for a list or how to check the time zones yourself on your installation.