# time displayed is wrong in Django template

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am trying to create a face detection program that will detect a face and log the time it was detected in. I created a Django template and am trying to display the time on the template. But the time it is displaying is wrong.

To double check, I tried printing the current time separately in a different python program. That displays the time correctly.

This is code for displaying the time in the Django template (info.html)

```
views.py

import datetime

def detect(request):

    global now
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

def info(request):
    return render(request, 'info.html', {'entry_time':now})
```

this is code I used in the separate python file

```
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

both the code is the same. I checked online and found this links
[How to get the current time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-python)

I also tried setting the timezone to my timezone (Asia/Kolkata) according to this link
[Is there a list of Pytz Timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866926/is-there-a-list-of-pytz-timezones)

I feel that I am not declaring the 'now' variable in the right place. 
Please help me out. I am new to Django

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the timezone in your `settings.py` and what is your actual timezone?

Comment: have you tried with django's  `timezone.now()`,  please refer this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: I changed the timezone in settings.py to TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'. This is my actual timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your settings.py change TIME_ZONE variable as you like.

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: I did that. But had to terminate the session and switch it bak again to see the changes. Thanks a lot.