# Change joined_at timezone discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone, discord.py

I've tried many methods involving `pytz` to change the timezone of the discord.py `user.joined_at` time. It's in UTC and I need it to be in EST.

What I did was

```
eastern = timezone('US/Eastern')
eastern.zone
fmt='%#c
jointime=eastern.localize(datetime(user.joined_at))
createtime=eastern.localize(datetime(user.created_at))
embed=discord.Embed(title='User Information:', color=0x0000ff)
embed.set_author(name='{0.name}'.format(user),icon_url='{0.avatar_url}'.format(user))
embed.add_field(name='Join Date:', value='{0.name} joined on'.format(user)+jointime.strftime(fmt))
embed.add_field(name='Account Creation:', value='{0.name}\'s account was created on '.format(user)+createtime.strftime(fmt))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the pytz module

```
from pytz import timezone

current_timezone_time = ctx.message.author.joined_at
new_timezone_time = current_timezone_time.astimezone(timezone('US/Pacific'))
#do whatever
```

In this example, I've converted it into `US/Pacific` but you can do [whichever one you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866926/is-there-a-list-of-pytz-timezones).

Comment: I have tried that and it hasn't worked for some reason

Comment: Depending on how it was generated, you may have to remind the `datetime` object that it's in UTC before you can convert it `ctx.message.author.joined_at.replace(tzinfo=timezone('UTC')).astimezone(timezone('US/Eastern'))`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh thx, the `datetime` object wasn't in UTC, so now I fixed it with `EST`