# Disable command on certain weekdays

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How to make this code work only on a specific date of the week like Saturday or Sunday, and other times return a custom message: *this command is been offline* or something similar.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    msg = "Pong {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
from datetime import datetime

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
  if datetime.now().strftime("%A") == "Saturday":
    await bot.say("This command is offline")
  else:
    msg = "Pong {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

Comment: Is this saturday which gmt time ?

Comment: To convert to different timezones you can `from pytz import timezone` and   `now_utc = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))` or if you want US/Pacific `now_pacific = datetime.now(timezone('US/Pacific'))` or whichever you want from [the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866926/is-there-a-list-of-pytz-timezones)