# Setting time zone of a Pandas Timestamp to Boise

Tags: python, pandas, timezone

I want to read in a unix time into a timestamp and assign the timezone of Boise. Current timezone there is "MDT – Mountain Daylight Time (Daylight Saving Time)". It will switch to MST during winter time.

What is the right timezone to use, when I want want to have it not dependent on summer / winter time?

I want to have something like this

```
pd.Timestamp(1513393355, unit='s', tz='US/Pacific')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This interprets `1513393355` as a timestamp in UTC and then converts the timestamp to the `America/Boise` timezone:

```
In [57]: pd.Timestamp(1513393355, unit='s', tz='UTC').tz_convert('America/Boise')
Out[57]: Timestamp('2017-12-15 20:02:35-0700', tz='America/Boise')
```

Pandas depends on `pytz` for timezone calculations. `pytz` depends on the Olson database. The Olson database contains a history of the utc offsets for each timezone. So you don't have to worry about whether Daylight Savings Time is in effect on a particular date. `tz_convert` will take care of that for you.

You can take a look at all the options using [`pytz.timezones`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13866926/190597).

There is a `US/Mountain` timezone, but it is [deprecated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).
See [Matt Johnson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55209845/190597) for more authoritative information on the relevant options.

Comment: Awesome - that was exactly what I was looking for. 'US/Mountain' works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

A few things:

- Generally speaking, one should use `America/Denver` for most of US Mountain Time, which currently switches between MST (UTC-7) and MDT (UTC-6).
- Use `America/Phoenix` for the part of US Mountain Time that does *not* currently use DST, such as applies in most (but not all) of Arizona.

  - However, be aware that it *used* to have DST in the past, last in 1968.
- Use `Etc/GMT+7` if you need a fixed offset that is UTC-7 and *never* had DST.  Be aware that the sign of the offset is inverted intentionally (`Etc/GMT+7` = `UTC-7`).

  - If you are using this zone for anything other than times for ships at sea, then you should probably re-evaluate this decision.  In other words, if your data is for a local time zone that *does* use DST, then you should not pick a zone that ignores it.
- You can use `America/Boise`, but you should only use it for the areas of southern Idaho and eastern Oregon that started DST four weeks late in 1974 (`1974-02-03` instead of `1974-01-06`), as described in [the commentary of the TZ Database sources](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2018i/northamerica#L781-L787):

  ```
  # Southern Idaho (Ada, Adams, Bannock, Bear Lake, Bingham, Blaine,
  # Boise, Bonneville, Butte, Camas, Canyon, Caribou, Cassia, Clark,
  # Custer, Elmore, Franklin, Fremont, Gem, Gooding, Jefferson, Jerome,
  # Lemhi, Lincoln, Madison, Minidoka, Oneida, Owyhee, Payette, Power,
  # Teton, Twin Falls, Valley, Washington counties, and the southern
  # quarter of Idaho county) and eastern Oregon (most of Malheur County)
  # switched four weeks late in 1974.
  ```

  - If you aren't working with timestamps from 1974, then you can ignore this zone and just use `America/Denver`.
- You *can* use `US/Mountain`, but understand that it is linked as an alias of `America/Denver` and is considered deprecated.  It exists for backwards compatibility.

  - It is generally recommended to use canonical identifiers of the `Area/Locality` form instead of these older representations.  Refer to the [list of TZ Database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) on Wikipedia.

Comment: OMG - did not know that it's so complex. Thanks for your comprehensive answer. My use case are current dates. So I will switch to "America/Boise".