# Python os.path.getmtime in UTC why

Tags: python, time, os.path

Several questions and sites such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58587891/getmtime-vs-datetime-now) and [here](https://newbedev.com/getmtime-vs-datetime-now) mention that Python's `getmtime` returns UTC based on documentation (`return os.path.getmtime(fileName)`). However, I cannot find in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) for the function why this must be so. Why must it be so? I am worried it is dependent on the OS and I must rely on it being the same for Windows, Linux, and MacOS.

I am working in Python 3.6 and 3.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

anytime you see

> The ... value is a floating point number giving the number of seconds since the epoch

that is by definition a utc timestamp since the epoch always refers to  `1/1/1970 00:00 UTC`

Comment: Although, the note in the `time` module may be worth considering: "**For Unix**, the epoch is January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 (UTC). **To find out what the epoch is on a given platform, look at time.gmtime(0)**."

Comment: @Carcigenicate on all3 OS listed it is always `1/1/1970 00:00 UTC` :) but yes i supose someone at somepoint in the future could buck this trend and break all softwares that depend on this fact