# How can I schedule a task in determinated hours?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

I want to run a task in week days, every 10 minutes between 8am and 17pm. I'm trying like this:

```py
cron = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True, timezone='UTC')
cron.add_job(service.test, trigger='cron',
             day_of_week='mon-fri', hour='7-16', minute=10)
cron.start()
```

but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The documentation states that "After the scheduler has been started, you can no longer alter its settings.". I'm not sure if setting refers to new jobs as well.

Comment: Also, UTC time right now is in the 20th hour, so it wouldn't work right now even if you added the job before you started the scheduler.

Comment: @Roy2012 it was set before calling start, but i changed to see if it worked.

Comment: So please change the code in the question to reflect that ...

Comment: @keanu i'm trying to get brazil's timezone

Comment: Look [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/brazil) and try replacing UTC with your timezone.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? Does your program end? Do you somehow keep it running?

Comment: @Roy2012 the job that I added it's never called

Comment: Does the program continue to run as a process on your machine?

Comment: yes. I'm starting to think that the problem it's the timezone, I tried to use my mine and raised a error 
" pytz.exceptions.UnknownTimeZoneError: 'BRT '"

Comment: It uses pytz for timezones, so you can look at the list of valid timezones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866926/is-there-a-list-of-pytz-timezones). I think `'Etc/GMT-3'` instead of `'BRT'` should work.

Comment: @keanu good suggestion, but still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

So, after a lot of research I found out that the problem wasn't the timezone, but me that didn't understood the code.

this:

```py
cron = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True, timezone=get_localzone())
cron.add_job(service.test, 'cron', day_of_week=(
    'mon-fri'), hour='7-16', minute=10)
```

means that at the 10th minute of every hour of every week day my code would be called, and not that it's going to be called every 10 minutes. Here's the docs of Cron-style scheduling, if someone wants to read more about https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/v2.1.2/cronschedule.html. Thanks everybody for helping!